# How to run eslint rules on just typescript files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a codebase with lots of .js and .ts/.tsx files. I want to run some rules on the whole codebase and some rules just on typescript files.

How can I achieve this in the best possible way?

specifically I want the rule: `"react/prop-types": "error",` to only run on .ts files

but it only gives one option of `error`, so not sure how to say just .ts for this?

Comment: I think you should use `tslint`  with `@typescript-eslint/parser`  and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` packages. Also check [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/linting-typescript-using-eslint-and-prettier/)

Comment: @Batuhan tslint had been deprecated (repo archived) for over a year when you wrote that comment https://github.com/palantir/tslint

Answer (score 0):

you can use an overrides option in your .eslintrc file:

```
{
  rules: {
    // all your general rules that apply to everyone
  },
  overrides: {
    files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
    rules: {
      // rules you want for ts/tsx files
      'react/prop-types': 'error',
    },
  },
}
```